# Douglas' lemma for integral operators

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Douglas' lemma gives a necessary and sufficient condition for two bounded operators $A$ and $B$ on a Hilbert space $H$ to get $\operatorname{Ran} A \subset \operatorname{Ran} B$ ([wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas%27_lemma), [original article](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-02/S0002-9939-1966-0203464-1/S0002-9939-1966-0203464-1.pdf)).

Does there exist a condition on two kernels $K_1$ and $K_2$ in order to get the inclusion of the ranges of the integral operators associated with? In order words, I am looking for a specific Douglas type lemma for integral operators which gives a condition on the kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Why don't use your third criterion: if $K_L$ is the kernel of the operator $L$, that gives you
$$
K_A=K_B\circ K_C,
$$
i.e.
$
K_A(x,y)=\int K_B(x,z) K_C(z,y) dz.
$

Comment: Well, but Douglas' result doesn't say that $C$ needs to be an integral operator, too.

Comment: Is there not a "Schwartz Kernel Theorem" in that context saying that all linear bounded operators must have a (distribution) kernel?